# Is there a way to insert new data into any location in a C# list?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm writing a program that basically creates a list of items. It first stores all the item numbers in a List of strings. After that, after each item, I want the program to store multiple lines of descriptions. Is there a way to add new data between two pre-existing points of data in the List without destroying any pre-existing data? I know in C++ you could push back a Vector, but I'm not sure if you can or how to do the same in C#.

Comment: You mean like using the [`List<T>.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method:

```
List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>();
myItems.Add(new Item("1"));
myItems.Insert(0, new Item("2"));
```

`Add` is used to add an object at the end of the list. `Insert` is used to insert element at the specified index.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following, you should be able to just use a generic.

```
var yourlist =new List<object>();
foreach (var result in results) { 
    var descriptionlist=new List<stirng>();
    descriptionlist.Add("line1");
    descriptionlist.Add("line2");
    descriptionlist.Add("line3");
    yourlist.Add(new {
        id = result.id,
        description = descriptionlist
    });
}
```